# what is db_clean in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

What is the use of **db_clean()** with a simple example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like `db_clean()` is a customized helper which is calling `xss_clean().`

See this [link,](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewreply/598074/) `db_clean()` is stored in MY_security_helper.php, whereby MY_ is the naming convention to extend native helper.

> ```
> xss_clean()
>
> Provides Cross Site Script Hack filtering. This function is an alias
> to the one in the Input class. More info can be found there.
> ```

Source: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/security_helper.html

Comment: So someone created their own helper and we have to give examples how to use that? You gave a nice answer to a strange question...